# How can I get Resources by name (string) and not by integer

Tags: android, resources

for example:

```
public final class R {

    public static final class raw {
        public static final int yuri=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

How can I get the resource by its name?
Without using R.raw.yuri = (int)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
getResources().getIdentifier( "yuri" , "raw" , getPackageName() );
```

I found this to be extremely slow.  I stripped it out of my whole project after doing some profiling and used `int[]` instead.

Comment: That's because this uses reflection. The performance really should only matter in a loop or something, and then you can cache the lookup.

Comment: Yes, we had what amounts to a bitmap font with one resource per letter and switching to an int[] of known constants was perceptibly faster.